# manipulating tumblr paging: do not count some posts

Tags: tumblr

I'm creating a blog with tumblr and I want that some types of post (the answer block) not to be displayed in the main page.

I already achieved this by changing the default code of my theme into

```
 {block:Answer}
      {block:TagPage}
        <article class="stat-answer" id="post-{PostID}">
         .......
      {/block:TagPage}
   {/block:Answer}
```

I basically added the `{/block:TagPage}`

Howeever it's still counting the posts.

This is a problem. I've many and I want to visualize them in a tag-page, NOT in the main page which will result blank because it counts the post wothout visualizing them.

How can say to tumblr not to count certain type of posts?

How is it possible, editing the html source?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your additional Tumblr markup you still output *Ask* posts, but not output the *Ask* info  if it a *Tag* page.

I think the problem is in order of cases. Try this code:

```
{block:TagPage}
    {block:Answer}
        <article class="stat-answer" id="post-{PostID}">
        …
        </article>
    {/block:Answer}
{/block:TagPage}
```

**UPD:** Due to my experience and [**this**](http://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/custom_themes) [**two**](http://disattention.com/labs/tumblr/theme-guide/) guides it is impossible to achieve your goal, because of normal behavior of *Tumblr*, which give you certain number of posts taken quite from database and due to *Tumblr-dev* logic, you must to output all of those received posts, And *Dev's* not checking if you are doing it right or not (outputing all received posts or selectively).

It is impossible to do it with pure Tumblr Markup, because of Theming API simplicity.

But you can use [**Tumblr API**](http://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/api/v2) to get, filter and output only necessary posts. This API have more flexibility, and may be it can help you.

Comment: I tried but it doesn't work. It still counts the ask posts. This is a problem. I've many and I want to visualize them in a tag-page, NOT in the main page which will result blank because it counts the post wothout visualizing them.

Comment: I think it is impossible with pure Tumblr markup, but you can use (**Tumblr API**](http://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/api/v2)

Comment: +1 for addressing me in the right place. It's not clear to me how can I use the api inside the tumblr eitor. Any example? thnx

Comment: http://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/api/v2#posts If you request this [**URI**](api.tumblr.com/v2/blog/{base-hostname}/posts[/type]?api_key={key}&[optional-params=]) you can filter response by checking this **type** key `"response": {"posts": [{"type": "text"}]}` to not be equal “answer”, and if so — output legible post.

Comment: it means that I have to re-render the page with a javascript, getting rid of all their templating engine, isn't it?

Comment: Yes, you will have to create your pages with *javascript*, with full control of all your customizations